# How to detect if a player has killed a mob? Minecraft 1.15.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I am making a function for a video, and I need a way to set a player's score to 1 when they kill a bat.

I was thinking I could just summon an invisible armor stand on every bat in the overworld, and use that to detect if a bat died near a player. However that could be very buggy, and may lag some users games.

Anyone got any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an objective with the `minecraft.killed:minecraft.bat` which will automatically increment each time you kill a bat.

```
/scoreboard objectives add batKills minecraft.killed:minecraft.bat
```

Comment: I had no idea the objective existed, thank you!